# hibernate @JoinTable annotation and criteria not working properly

Tags: java, hibernate, entity-relationship, dao, criteria-api

I have a Tag class which stores a reference to the set of Statuses using the TagStatus join table, currently there is no entity for it in the system

```
package com.iit.awt.application.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="System_Table_Tag")
public class Tag implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4142565751324734722L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="TagId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long tagId;

    @Column(name="TagText")
    private String tagText;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "System_Table_Tag_Status",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="TagId")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="StatusId")})
    private List<Status> statuses;

    public Long getTagId() {
        return tagId;
    }

    public void setTagId(Long tagId) {
        this.tagId = tagId;
    }

    public String getTagText() {
        return tagText;
    }

    public void setTagText(String tagText) {
        this.tagText = tagText;
    }

    public void setStatuses(List<Status> statuses) {
        this.statuses = statuses;
    }

    public List<Status> getStatuses() {
        return statuses;
    }

}
```

I am automatically retrieving data dynamically from the front, to do this whenever the statuses are displayed the latest status is stored and all the statuses afterwards are shown (with a greater statusId value as the id is auto incremented)

This is my dao class function here

```
@Override
public List<Tag> getTagDetailsUsingTagTextWithStatusFiltering(
        String profileText, Long latestStatus) {
    Criteria criteria = super.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Tag.class);

    if(profileText!=null && profileText!=""){
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("tagText", profileText));
    }

    if(latestStatus!=null){
        criteria.createAlias("statuses", "stts");
        criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("stts.statusId", latestStatus));
    }

    return criteria.list();
}
```

Even though it seems to work fine all of the statuses are returned. HOWEVER lets say the latest status id 37 and there were no new statuses the filtering would work fine and nothing new would be returned BUT if there is a new status such as with a status id  of 38 ALL the statuses would be returned whereas I only wanted one

Any help as soon as possible is greatly appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. A Tag has a set of statuses, and the collection of statuses in the Tag class contains all these statuses. If it didn't, and you added a status to the set of statuses in the tag, would you expect all the non-loaded statuses to be deleted from the database? Moreover, your query does the following:

```
select tag from Tag tag inner join tag.statuses status where status.statuesId > :latestStatus
```

So it only fetches tags. Then, since you configured the collection of stateses to be eagrely fetched, the set of statuses of the tag is loaded, in an additional query, from the database.

If you want to load a partial view of entities, then you shouldn't load entities.

Note that Hibernate allows loading partial entities, but you should use this feature with caution, because it's very dangerous. Only use these partial entities as if they were read-only DTOs. Also note that this behavior is not supported by other JPA engines.

If you want to load a tag with a partial set of its statuses, you should do it in a single query, by adding a fetch mode for the statuses:

```
criteria.setFetchMode("statuses", FetchMode.JOIN);
```